# Ingesting a log file into HDFS using Flume while it is being written

Tags: real-time, flume, reliability

What is the best way to ingest a log file into HDFS while it is being written ? I am trying to configure Apache Flume, and am trying to configure sources that can offer me data reliability as well. I was trying to configure "exec" and later also looked at "spooldir" but the following documentation at flume.apache.org has put doubt on my own intent -

**Exec Source:**

> One of the most commonly requested features is the use case like-
>   "**tail -F file_name**" where an application writes to a log file on disk and
>   Flume tails the file, sending each line as an event. While this is
>   possible, there’s an obvious problem; what happens if the channel
>   fills up and Flume can’t send an event? Flume has no way of indicating
>   to the application writing the log file, that it needs to retain the
>   log or that the event hasn’t been sent for some reason. Your
>   application can never guarantee data has been received when using a
>   unidirectional asynchronous interface such as ExecSource!

**Spooling Directory Source:**

> Unlike the Exec source, "spooldir" source is reliable and will not
>   miss data, even if Flume is restarted or killed. In exchange for this
>   reliability, only immutable files must be dropped into the spooling
>   directory. If a file is written to after being placed into the
>   spooling directory, Flume will print an error to its log file and stop
>   processing.

Anything better is available that I can use to ensure Flume will not miss any event and also reads in realtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Spooling Directory Source, because of its reliability. A workaround for the inmmutability requirement is to compose the files in a second directory, and once they reach certain size (in terms of bytes or amount of logs), move them to the spooling directory.

Comment: Sure, but then it is not **while it is being written** (Its kind of off line).

Comment: In that case, Exec Source is the only chance for you. Well, not only. You can create a custom source achieving your needs, an "Exec Source 2" able to communicate with the application writting the logs (maybe through another file where not processed logs are written)... Just brainstorming ;)